# Magento API not sending my email

Tags: php, magento

When creating a guest user through the API, my email is not send to the webshop. The call is as follows:

```
shoppingCartCustomerSet', $this->sessionId, $this->cartId, [
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'email' => $email,
    'mode' => $mode,
    'website_id' => $this->shopId
], $this->shopId );
```

Mode is set to 'guest' and email = 'test@test.nl', but somehow I don't see my email back in the order overview in the magento dashboard. Is this because I'm using the mode as guest?

Comment: Have you check log file during the execution of this code?

Comment: Yes, no errors where shown. The feature I want is not default behaviour of Magento.